# Dynamic DNS for EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns

Sorry if this question was asked earlier, please provide a link to the discussion or answer.

I create and destroy EC2 instances and deploy applications on it. Is the instance considered a Pet if I were to associate a dynamic DNS for the instance.

Are meaningful names for cloud instances considered a PET even if there is no memory of the instance other than the name?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Can you describe your use-case? Or is this just a general question?

Comment: Are you referring to the AWS theory of "cattle" versus "pets"? EC2 instances should be designed as "cattle". I am not sure of your reference to Dynamic DNS - this is generally a bad idea to include into a design.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: The use case is for an application that is launched in an EC2 instance, it is reachable through a browser. This is mostly in development, no load balancer in front of it. When the application is updated, destroy the old instance, create a new EC2 instance install the new application. This will assign new ip address, but to reach it, my suggestion was to have a meaningful name for it to be reachable even though the instance gets assigned new ip address. There were few who said, that will make the instance a PET. I'm just curious to understand is that considered a PET

Comment: @JohnHanley: For new EC2 instances, would like to have a meaningful name associated with the ip addresses assigned, that's why i said dynamic DNS.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have a consistent name to access an application running on a single Amazon EC2 instance, then:

- Create an **Elastic IP Address**
- Assign it to the instance
- Purchase/Create a **Domain Name** (eg `app.mydomain.com`) in Amazon Route 53
- Create an `A` record in Route 53 to associate the domain name with the Elastic IP address

In future, if the instance is terminated and replaced with a new instance, simply **assign the Elastic IP Address to the new instance** and it will be instantly accessible via the same domain name.

Comment: Thanks. What if this is for internal domain names not a public domain. Also, the question is more from the point of view of what is considered PET vs Cattle.

Comment: You can also define VPC-scoped domain names within Route 53. If it is only being accessed internally, then skip the Elastic IP address and simply point the A-Record to the internal IP address. If a new instance is created, you'll need to update the A-Record. The instance could actually do this itself when it boots up by running a command in the startup (User Data) script that updates the A-Record to point to itself.